# Import 5 dimensions from Excel into GAMS

Tags: excel, modeling, gams-math

I have a parameter with 4 dimensions which I would like to import in Excel.

Currently I have a series of Excel sheets with each over 500,000 rows. The columns are:

- Parcel,
- Farm,
- Year,
- Species,
- Class,
- Surface

Ideally I would like to have a parameter in GAMS like: `Surface(Parcel,Farm,Year,Species,Class)`

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

For those interested, the solution is as simple as this:

```
$CALL GDXXRW.EXE DeParcels2012_GAMS.xlsx par=input2012  rdim=5
```

The number of dimensions can be specified in the gdxxrw tool.